# What does compress mean in SAS using ||

Tags: sas

What does compress function mean in SAS using ||?
for example:

```
compress("test:" || 'price_data' || ":")
```

is it just for connecting strings using ||?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double pipe `||` operator appends strings together.

The `compress()` function removes all blanks from the argument.

In this case, the compress function does nothing because the three appended string literals clearly contain no blanks. There is furthermore no reason to use appending since, again, it's all literals.
Your statement is equivalent to this `"test:price_data:"`

Now, if, as it seems to be the case, `price_data` is supposed to be a variable, then you would need to remove the single quotes surrounding it and that statement would then make total sense

```
compress("test:"||price_data||":")
```

This produces a string that is the value of `price_data` prepended with the string `test` and appended with a colon and in which all blanks (i.e. any blanks that would have been introduced by `price_data`) were removed by the `compress` function.